# Examples of primitive rings containing some, but not all, finite rank operators

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, linear-transformations

If $D$ is a division ring and $V$ is a vector space over $D$, then a subring $R$ of $\mathrm{End}_D(V)$ is *dense* if for any $n$ linearly independent vectors $v_1,\ldots, v_n$ and any vectors $w_1,\ldots, w_n$, there exists $r\in R$ with $rv_i=w_i$ for $i=1,\ldots, n$.  [Jacobson's density theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobson_density_theorem) says that any primitive ring has a faithful representation as a ring of dense operators.

It is well known that the collection of all finite rank operators on $V$ is a dense ring (I don't require rings to be unital).  Here is my question:

> > If a dense ring of operators on $V$ contains a finite rank operator, must it contain all finite rank operators?

This is obviously the case if $V$ is finite dimensional.  I am primarily interested in the case that $V$ has countably infinite dimension.  If it makes a difference, I would be willing to let $D$ be an algebraically closed field.

Comment: Good question. The linear transformations of finite rank form a minimal ideal in the full ring of transformations, so it would be interesting if some dense subring did not contain it.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but [here are the interesting non-Artinian primitive rings](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=74r&L=63l) that I know.  Unfortunately, I find many of them hard to reason about. A good deal of them are von Neumann regular too, if that helps. Some of them are domains, and that might help. The conjecture could not hold for a right-primitive domain if it contained a finite rank operator, because then there would be nilpotent elements, I think. But maybe right-primitive domains can't contain finite rank operators to begin with...

Comment: @rschweib left primitive domains cannot have a finite rank operator of the dimension is not 1 because this implies there is a rank one operator (take a minimal rank non zero operator and use density to move its image to intersect its kernel). Now using the same argument you can move the image of a rank one operator to its kernel to get a zero divisor.

Comment: Nice... that gets us down to what I consider [the hard ones](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=74r&L=63r&L=8) then. Btw, please use tab completion on my username lest typos prevent your alerts from reaching me.

Comment: @rschwieb, the O’meara looks promising to me.